# Access Google Fit steps count on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm working a face watch for Android Wear. I want to read the steps which the watch counts (those displayed on the card). Are there any easy ways to access the data? 
My research showed that I can either create my own steps counter (which I don't want because of the accuracy problem). The other is do access the Google Api. However I find it very "weighty" on the code to implement it along side my phone battery function. Is there any other way to retrieve the data?

I don't want this to be connected with the phone app, but only with the one on the watch.

I found more info here but it is a bit old: [Access Android Wear Fit Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603535/access-android-wear-fit-data)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily access the step count on the watch by using the Sensor API, using the Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER. More info here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-stepcounter

Answer (score 2):

Yet, it is an old question but maybe this answer will help someone in future.
Since 2015 GoogleApis are a bit easier to use.

To get daily total steps (same as in google fit) there is HistoryApi with it's method:

[`Fitness.HistoryApi.readDailyTotal(googleApiClient, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)`;](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/HistoryClient#readDailyTotal(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType))

There is a blog post on [reading daily steps](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total). Some informations are also in [Work with the Fitness History](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history) chapter, especially if you want to use data from other time ranges.
By the way, as I remember to read daily steps you do not have to ask for any scopes (api permissions).

[Wear 1.0]

In wear 1.0 there is no google accounts support, thus all you can do is to use `readDailyTotal()` method. To make this work, you have to call [`useDefaultAccount()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#useDefaultAccount()) method while building your client.

[Wear 2.0]

I'm not sure whether the method with default account from wear 1.0 will still work on wear 2.0 devices but it's ok. Thanks [Google Sign-In](http://%20https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), using accounts on wear is not a pain ;) Just follow the steps in the  link above and it should be good.

Google Sign-In will provide you an Google account that you can use with GoogleApi clients.

One notice, when I used Google Developer Console to generate OAUTH  configuration json file it did not work. Just use the Sign-In site to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've done your research pretty well. Getting the data from the Google API is indeed a bit complicated. But if you don't want to create your own step counter, that's what you have to do. I recently helped AliceOS setting up the connection properly to the Fit API. Perhaps the sample code mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295189/issue-with-google-fit-api-on-android-wear) could help you too. It should at least be up to date. Good luck!